# How do I echo a string with multiple spaces in bash "untouched"?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I assigned a var like this:

```
MYCUSTOMTAB='     '
```

But using it in echo both:

```
echo $MYCUSTOMTAB"blah blah"
```

or

```
echo -e $MYCUSTOMTAB"blah blah"
```

just returns a **single space** and the rest of the string:

```
 blah blah
```

How can I print the full string untouched? I want to use it for have a custom indent because `\t` is too much wide for my tastes.

Comment: Put the variable *inside* double quotes. This is one of the main reasons we constantly harp "quote your variables". [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Put your variable inside double quote to prevent [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), which *ate* your spaces:

```
$ MYCUSTOMTAB='     '
$ echo "${MYCUSTOMTAB}blah blah"
     blah blah
```

Answer (score 13):

As suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273665/133107) quoting the variable is enough.

The reason why quoting is needed in your case is because without it bash applies the split+glob operator onto the expansion of `$MYCUSTOMTAB`. The default value of `$IFS` contains the TAB character, so in `echo -e $MYCUSTOMTAB"blah blah"`, `$MYCUSTOMTAB` is just split into nothing so it becomes the same as if you had written:

```
echo -e "blah blah"
```

(you probably don't want `-e` here btw).

You can also use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$MYCUSTOMTAB"

printf '%s\n' "${MYCUSTOMTAB}blah blah"
```

Or if you want `printf` to do the same kind of `\n`, `\t` expansions that `echo -e` does, use `%b` instead of `%s`:

```
printf '%b\n' "${MYCUSTOMTAB}blah blah"
```

For reference read [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: While strictly true, the cause here is totally unrelated to the difference between `printf` and `echo`. While `printf` is certainly more portable and has some upsides, its major downside is that it is ugly and unreadable, and way more difficult to understand.

Comment: printf is "better" if you use it properly: you need to write `printf "blah%sblah\n" "$MYCUSTOMTAB"` -- if the variable contains any %s, %d, etc, you'll get the wrong output otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to use double quotes for your variable

```
echo -e "$MYCUSTOMTAB"."blah blah"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In output I get the dot - it's not a concatenation operator in this case. However the following is working: 
`echo "$MYCUSTOMTAB""blah blah"`

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is tagged `bash` but anyway, for maximum portability and reliability, I would use:

```
printf "%sblah blah\n" "$MYCUSTOMTAB"
```

or

```
someString="blah blah"
printf "%s%s\n" "$MYCUSTOMTAB" "$someString"
```