# spaces between date format

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

what's the best way in shell to create custom date format and adding any space between the format?

For example the below command for print yesterday date by the format **Oct 9**

```
custom_format="$(date -d '-1 day' '+%b %-d')"; echo $custom_format
```

Now I need to add two spaces between the month and the day but usually not working with me, I tested also to using `%t` to adding tap space but not working with this format.

```
custom_format="$(date -d '-1 day' '+%b **spaces here** %-d')"; echo $custom_format
```

Comment: This is more about unquoted variables than the `date` command - see for example [How do I echo a string with multiple spaces in bash “untouched”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273660/how-do-i-echo-a-string-with-multiple-spaces-in-bash-untouched)

Comment: @steeldriver it's worked well

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with the `date` command itself (just insert the spacing in the format string in whatever way you want).  The issue is with the `echo` and the way that you do *not* quote the expansion of `$custom_format`.

When you don't quote `$custom_format`, the shell will split its value into words based on the characters in `$IFS` (space, tab and newline by default), and will then perform filename generation (globbing) on the resulting words.

This means that your command `echo $custom_format` will be transformed into something like `echo Oct  9`, which is `echo` invoked with two arguments, regardless how many spaces there are between them, and `echo` would output each, one after the other, with a single delimiting space in-between.

To get the output you are looking for, use double quotes around `$custom_format` when calling `echo` with it as an argument.

See also

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Steeldriver, I fixed it by using the below syntax

```
yesterday_day="$(date -d '-1 day' '+%-d')"
yesterday_month="$(date -d '-1 day' '+%b')"
yesterday="${yesterday_month}   ${yesterday_day}"
```

and now you can add any spaces you want inside it

Comment: That's no different from `yesterday=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%b <three spaces here>  %-d')` and is not fixing anything. If you write `echo $yesterday` _unquoted_, as in your example, there would be a _single_ space between the month and the day.